# Images are not loading on codepen on chrome?

Tags: html, css, codepen

The images work on Firefox and chrome when I'm using local storage for the images but when I upload the images to imgur and load them into codepen -- it only works on Firefox, the images don't load at all on chrome, why would this be?

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/OBiyZL0.jpg" alt="Blog Thumbnail">
background: url('https://i.imgur.com/6RELfrW.jpg') no-repeat;
```

This is how I am doing it, the CSS is for a different element from the html shown but neither work on codepen/chrome.

Also, the navbar on chrome doesn't work correctly, why does the  justify-content: right; not work?

codepen in question: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBRJEN

Answer (score 0):

Imgur image is giving `403 error`. Instead of imgur try with some online image service for example https://imgbb.com/. It will work.

Image link I used is https://ibb.co/cDR14J

```
.splashCover {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://ibb.co/cDR14J') no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: top;
  filter: opacity(.6);
}
```

Below is working code pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpyRMO